# Forbid overriding of a method in a derived class

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, overriding

Here is my class and I don't want this method to be overridden in child classes, how can I accomplish this behaviour ?

```
class A 
{ 
   public virtual void demo() 
   { 
   } 
} 

class B : A 
{ 
   public override void demo() 
   { 
   } 
} 

// when Class B be inherited in C, methods can be overridden further, 
// but I don't want the method to be overridden further.
class C : B 
{ 

}
```

Comment: Do you want to make this method [sealed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw.aspx) ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

put '`sealed`' modifier before `override void demo()`

```
class A 
{ 
    public virtual void demo() 
    { 
    } 
} 

class B:A 
{ 
    public sealed override void demo() 
    { 
    } 
} 

//B can be inherited in C but demo() method can not be overriden further 
class C:B 
{ 

}
```

Answer (score 11):

You just need the [`sealed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw.aspx) modifier:

```
public sealed override void demo() 
{ 
    // Whatever implementation
}
```

(I assume it would normally be a name conforming to the .NET conventions, of course.)

If you want to prevent the method from being overridden without changing the behaviour yourself, you need to override it but explicitly call the previous behaviour:

```
public sealed override void demo() 
{ 
    base.demo();
}
```

Note that when applied to a method (or property), `sealed` can *only* be applied in conjunction with `override`.